# How to hide certain targets in CMake?

Tags: c++, configuration, cmake

I have a library that is built as part of my CMake-based project. This library has many targets and I am not interested in seeing them appearing in my target list (either under Visual Studio or QtCreator). Is there a way for me to have this library built as part of my project build (kindda like a dependency build) but not seeing the available targets of this library?

Comment: There is a [`FOLDER` property](http://devdocs.io/cmake~3.8/prop_tgt/folder) that I had hoped would at least let me shunt unimportant targets to a `misc` folder. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to do anything with Qt Creator 4.3.0.

Answer (score 4):

There is currently little explicit support for hiding specific targets in these IDEs. CMake does not (yet) support a show/hide targets option. However, there is a way to avoid scrolling through long lists of targets in Visual Studio; you can *group* your targets with IDEs folders. CMake supports this, by setting the [`FOLDER`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/FOLDER.html#prop_tgt:FOLDER) property on specific targets.

First, tell CMake to enable IDE folders by adding this line to your top-level CMakeLists.txt file:

```
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)
```

Then, organize your targets into folders, by setting the `FOLDER` property.

```
# Put these targets in the 'HiddenTargets' folder in the IDE.
set_target_properties(SillyLib1 SillyLib2 DontCareLib1 PROPERTIES FOLDER HiddenTargets)
# Put these targets in the 'AppTools' folder in the IDE.
set_target_properties(WriterLib1 ReaderLib1 AwesomeLib42 PROPERTIES FOLDER AppTools)
```

Now, your CMake targets will be placed in the `HiddenTargets` and `AppTools` folders in the Visual Studio **Solution Explorer**. You can collapse the folders containing targets you don't want to see, or hide the folder altogether (by right-clicking the folder, and selecting **Hide Folder**). The targets will still be usable (and will be built if necessary), they just won't be visible in the **Solution Explorer**. You can un-hide hidden folders by right-clicking the solution, and selecting **Unhide Folders**.

---

Qt Creator does not support this, to my knowledge. However, in 2017, they addressed a similar [request](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-17972) to hide CMake targets. In general, this bug fix (implemented in Qt Creator 4.4.0 and greater) cleaned up the polluted targets view (removed the **Source Directory** listing), and improved their **Hide Generated Files** and **Hide Empty Folders** capabilities, which gave users more control over what is shown/hidden in the project listing.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this is to have CMake execute a shell command that builds the dependencies I need instead of calling [add_subdirectory](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_subdirectory.html). It's not elegant but beats the visual pollution caused by all those unwanted targets.

Answer (score -1):

Do you know the [ExternalProject_Add](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#module%3aExternalProject) command? It allows you to describe build (and download, patch, install, ...) steps of libraries that you want to build as a prerequisite of 
your own project. Using this command will show your library as a single target in make/Visual Studio/QtCreator.